# Can I use the dotnet msbuild command for SonarQube?

Tags: sonarqube, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

Can I use the `dotnet msbuild` command instead of MSBuild task with the VSTS Sonarcube extension (SonarQube scanner for MSBuild) as it has the exact same capabilities?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-msbuild

> The command has the exact same capabilities as existing MSBuild
>   command-line client. The options are all the same. Use the MSBuild
>   Command-Line Reference to obtain information on the available options.

[Click here to See how I configured VSTS for SonarQube](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6ewh.png)

Answer (score 0):

To used the Sonar in your build process, you need to install SonarQube task. This task is free, and you see and install in [Visual Studio Market Place](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SonarSource.sonarqube).
You need to add this tasks to enable the Sonar analysis, and setup sonar endpoint.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I have already added the extension and configured accordingly. See the question I have updated the question with an image link.

However I'm getting an error when I execute the build.

Answer (score 0):

There is [SonarQube 3.0.2 extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SonarSource.sonarqube) available and it supports .Net Core project (Need to update extension manually if installed SonarQube 2.0 extension)

However, based on the test, dotnet msbuild command doesn’t work fine for Sonarcube, using Visual Studio Build Task works fine. You can submit user voice on SonarQube site.

So, I recommend that you can use Visual Studio Build Task instead.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.  I have already added the extension and configure the endpoints. (Please check, since I'm unable to upload the image here I had edit the question and updated with image link)

How ever when I execute the build, I'm getting following errors

Comment: 2017-09-11T07:54:23.2040869Z ##[error]The SonarQube MSBuild integration failed: SonarQube was unable to collect the required information about your projects.
2017-09-11T07:54:23.2040869Z ##[error]Possible causes:
2017-09-11T07:54:23.2040869Z ##[error]1. The project has not been built - the project must be built in between the begin and end steps

Comment: 2017-09-11T07:54:23.2040869Z ##[error]2. An unsupported version of MSBuild has been used to build the project. Currently MSBuild 14.0 upwards are supported
2017-09-11T07:54:23.2040869Z ##[error]3. The begin, build or end steps have not all been launched from the same folder
2017-09-11T07:54:23.2040869Z ##[error]07:54:23.189  Post-processing failed. Exit code: 1

Comment: @Kumara I get the error related to SonarQube.Integration.targets (before complete the sonarqube analysis task) Does the Command Line task work fine in your build?